# Apache Spark data modelling - should I prefer denormalisation or joins for query performance?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata, data-modeling

I have two logical data tables - the first contains raw data financial data with about 500 million rows per day. The second is a reference data table containing about 10,000 rows per day, with some 100 columns. Each row in the raw data will have a corresponding row in the reference data.

I need to run ad-hoc Spark queries that cut, slice and aggregate the raw financial data depending on supplied reference data parameters.

Question - is it better to denormalise the data such that each raw data row also contains all 100 reference data items, or instead do a join from raw to reference by some key?

Answer (score 0):

The performance will bet best if you completely denormalise the data and write to Parquet. With Parquet columnar compression you will get great compression on your dimension attributes.

If you were to join the two data sets make sure to use a broadcast join. The broadcast join will broadcast your smaller table to all mappers and you can perform a map side join without shuffle

BTW, it should be quick to test the two scenarios. You can then compare performance and data size of the two use cases and make an informed decision

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.. do you have a good example of a broadcast join I can read through?

Comment: The Catalyst CBO should take care of that automatically. I presume it requires statistics on your table(s) https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html